# Replacing "he" with "she" in a string (overlaps with "the")

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

(Javascript) Say there is a string:

```
str = "The goat he wanted was the grey one"
```

I try to do:

```
str = str.replace('he', 'she');
```

The output I get is "Tshe goat she wanted was tshe grey one". However, the output I want is "The goat she wanted was the grey one"

How would I go about changing "he" to "she", but also not replacing the "he" in the word "the"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472010/replacing-only-whole-word-not-words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the

```
str.replace('he','she');
```

with

```
str.replace(/\she/),'she');
```

the `\s` represents a space, so (assuming the string follows proper english grammar), it would only replace the word "he" if there is a space before it (which should be so because you put a space between every word).

Comment: This worked out nicely and was simple for me to understand as I'm a bit new to string manipulation. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. You should probably use the other answers as well, as I find out they are more reliable than mine. Still, happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

```
str = "The goat he wanted was the grey one"
str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + 'he' + '\\b'), 'she');
alert(str);
```

Use wordboundries instead, by putting boundry marks up. See above example

and a JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/1s73qax8/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a RegExp object: `str.replace(/(^|[^A-Za-z\-_0-9])he($|[^\-_A-Za-z0-9])/, '$1she$2')`. This doesn't isolate 'he' from all Unicode letters. You could consider looking at my old [UnicodeGeneralCategory](https://github.com/hydroper/com.hydroper.util.CharCategory) attempt to validate letter characters or otherwise search on [NPM](https://npmjs.com) for text manipulation.

Comment: why not just use dot( . ) instead of (^|[^A-Za-z\-_0-9])

Comment: @AkashSarode This group works like a lookbehind. If it were '.', any character could precede 'he'.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression word boundary. Place the text you're trying to replace between /\b \b/. Like

```
str = str.replace('/\bhe\b/','she');
```